# Can I use the same Vector2 struct across multiple librarys that implement their own Vector2 structs?

Tags: c#, .net, game-engine, game-physics, monogame

I'm making a 2D game that will use one library for rendering graphics to the screen, and another for physics. The problem is that both libraries implement their own Vector2 struct. This means I have to convert between the two very often and it can be confusing which Vector2 I'm referring to because they are both called "Vector2". Ideally, I would like to use the same Vector2 class across both libraries. How can I achieve this with C#?

Comment: @stuartd I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean. If I implement my own Vector2 struct in a shared library, I wouldn't be able to pass an instance of it into a function in the physics library because the physics library function is expecting the parameter type to be of its implementation of Vector2, not the one in the shared library.

Comment: @stuartd I'm pretty sure OP means they are using third party libraries for graphics and physics; They probably won't be able to modify those libraries to reference a common library & vector type.

Comment: @Romen I guess so, I didn't think of 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own `MyVector2` struct that supports [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) to the other `Vector2` types.

```csharp
struct MyVector2
{
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public static implicit operator GraphicsLib.Vector2(MyVector2 v)
    { return new GraphicsLib.Vector2(v.x,v.y); }

    public static implicit operator PhysicsLib.Vector2(MyVector2 v)
    { return new PhysicsLib.Vector2(v.x,v.y); }

    ...
}
```

Then instances of `MyVector2` should be compatible with any function expecting a `Vector2` from either library.

```csharp
MyVector2 v = new MyVector2(5f, 20f);
GraphicsLib.DoSomethingWithVector(v);
PhysicsLib.DoSomethingWithVector(v);
```

The other answer that mentions using `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.As<MyVector2, PhysicsLib.Vector2>(ref v);` might also be possible to use inside the conversion operators if optimization is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

If they have the same internal layout, you can use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` to convert between them. You can also create extension methods that for each kind. E.g.  `public static Lib1.Vector2 ToLib1(this Lib2.Vector2 v) = > System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.As<Lib2.Vector2, Lib1.Vector2>(ref v);`
Personally, I use MonoGame but use System.Numerics.Vector2 everywhere I can for SIMD support (it might be an unnecessary micro-optimization but I sleep better knowing that I use SIMD instructions when I can).